# How to use the AAA syntax to do an AssertWasCalled but ignore arguments

Tags: rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

I'm using the new AAA syntax and wanted to know the syntax to do the below and have the mock ignore the arguments:

```
mockAccount.AssertWasCalled(account => account.SetPassword("dsfdslkj"));
```

I think the below is how I would do this with the record/ replay model but I wanted to see if this could be done with AAA using 3.6:

```
mockAccount.Expect(account => account.SetPassword("sdfdsf")).IgnoreArguments();
mockAccount.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it with the obvious google search - hope someone else finds this of value

```
mockAccount.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.SetPassword(""), y => y.IgnoreArguments());
```

Answer (score 16):

To ignore the arguments, use Arg<string>.Is.Anything:

```
mockAccount.AssertWasCalled(acc => acc.SetPassword(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
```